# Pyqgis: Style Layer After Processing with qml file

Tags: pyqgis

I'm doing a spatial join, but the styling doesn't work. What needs to be fixed?

```
##Style=name
##drivetimepoints=vector
##gridwgs84layer=vector
##DriveTimeGrid=output vector
outputs_QGISJOINATTRIBUTESBYLOCATION_1=processing.runalg('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', gridwgs84layer,drivetimepoints,['intersects'],0.0,0,'sum,mean,min,max,median',0,DriveTimeGrid)
layer = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISJOINATTRIBUTESBYLOCATION_1['OUTPUT'])
layer.loadNamedStyle("C:/QGIS Style File/Drive Time Grids.qml")
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your script has finished, your output is loaded onto canvas. What you are doing is applying the style ***before*** the output is loaded into QGIS. So the style is not applied correctly. There is an option in the interface when you run your script:

[image: Script interface]

---

You can apply the style in a couple of ways:

1. Load the layer in your script and **uncheck** the option from the interface:

   ```
   ##Style=name
   ##drivetimepoints=vector
   ##gridwgs84layer=vector
   ##DriveTimeGrid=output vector

   from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry

   outputs_QGISJOINATTRIBUTESBYLOCATION_1=processing.runalg('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', gridwgs84layer,drivetimepoints,['intersects'],0.0,0,'sum,mean,min,max,median',0,DriveTimeGrid)
   layer = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISJOINATTRIBUTESBYLOCATION_1['OUTPUT'])
   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
   layer.loadNamedStyle("C:/QGIS Style File/Drive Time Grids.qml")
   layer.triggerRepaint()
   ```
2. Add the `Set style for vector layer` algorithm and again **uncheck** the option from the interface:

   ```
   ##Style=name
   ##drivetimepoints=vector
   ##gridwgs84layer=vector
   ##DriveTimeGrid=output vector

   outputs_QGISJOINATTRIBUTESBYLOCATION_1=processing.runalg('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', gridwgs84layer,drivetimepoints,['intersects'],0.0,0,'sum,mean,min,max,median',0,DriveTimeGrid)
   layer = processing.getObject(outputs_QGISJOINATTRIBUTESBYLOCATION_1['OUTPUT'])
   outputs_QGISSETSTYLEFORVECTORLAYER=processing.runalg("qgis:setstyleforvectorlayer", layer, "C:/QGIS Style File/Drive Time Grids.qml")
   ```